# Offset vba object

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple Macro that has been working for months and now all of the sudden its broken when I reformatted (clue but I cant figure it out). I know the problem center around the offset function, which seems to have some problems.

I would like to use something else (Cells) but I cant figure out how.

Specifically, I have a Range that I am checking through and altering nearby cells.

Is there a way to do something like this with 'Cells'

```
Dim x As Variant
x = Worksheets("Book1").Range("A131")
If (x = some value And x>0) Then
x.Offset(0,7).Value = some value
End if
```

now excel is showing me an error that Object is required

Comment: On which line of code is the error occurring?

Comment: Can you update your code to exactly the code that's causing the problem? For example having `(x = some value ` would be error-prone since `some value` is 2 words... Please be more explicit in your code sample so we can more easily determine where the problem is...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use SET:

```
SET x = Worksheets("Book1").Range("A131")
```

When you don't use SET you are returning the value that is in the Cell, not the actual range object (which is required to use Offset())...  after using X use x.Value to return the contents of the cell.

Comment: thanks, but I am using SET in the macro for the Range Value. Sorry I didnt use in the sample code as the 'For each's get annying to read

Comment: I tested your code as you posted it and it returned the error you mentioned ("object is required). I changed it to include SET and it worked as expected.  Can you update your question with the code you are actually using?

Answer (score 1):

Your code using Cells():

```
Dim x As Variant
Dim ws as Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Book1")
x = ws.Cells(131, 1).Value ' row 131, column 1 (A131)
If (x = some value And x>0) Then
   ws.Cells(138, 1).Value = someValue ' row 138, column 1 (A138)
End if
```